# Simplest way for generating multiple sets of fields for nested associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Models: Jobs, Applications, Questions, Answers

```
Jobs has_many questions 
     has many Applications 
Applications has_many answers
             belongs_to :job 
Questions
     has_one :answer
     belongs_to :job
```

In the Application view, I would like to create a view that lists all the questions a particular job has, and gives the corresponding field for the answers.

Right now, I'm able to do that in a bit of a hacked way.

I think the best way to do it is to run 2 simultaneous loops, one of which is an array of questions, @questions, and the other one, which is fields_for :answers

Then, in the fields_for tag, I could provide the question.id, as well as the question.content

**Is there a way to do this?**

This is my current strategy

```
<%= form_for [@job, @application]  do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <% @job.questions.each do |question| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :answers, question do |a| %> #This is the hacked part
      <%= a.label :content, question.content %>
      <%= a.text_area :content, value: "" %>
      <%= a.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %> 
    <% end %>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit the application", class: "button" %>
 <% end %>
```

What I'm doing there is passing the question object as the object for the fields_for tag.

This is my controller ->

```
  def new 
   job = params[:job_id]
   @application = Application.build(job)
   redirect_to jobs_path, :notice => "You've already applied to this job! Check out some more" if has_job(current_user,@job)
  end
```

And Application Model ->

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job
    belongs_to :user
    validates :job_id, presence: true 
    validates :user_id, presence: true 

  has_many :questions, through: :job
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true


   def self.build(job_id)
       application = self.new

       job = Job.find(job_id)
       job.questions.count.times do
           application.answers.build
       end

       application
    end

end
```

I found this --> http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loop_over_multiple_arrays_simultaneously#Ruby ,

But I'm not sure if that can be implemented with a fields_for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a problem with your associations. It seems you want a Job to be able to have many applications and its own set of questions. Each application will then have a set of answers with each answer corresponding to one question in the Job posting. Reflecting this, you would have the ff associations:

```
Job has_many :questions 
     has many :applications 
Application has_many :answers
            belongs_to :job 
Question has_many :answer
          belongs_to :job
Answer belongs_to :application
       belongs_to :question
```

Then we do this in the model:

```
def build_answers
  job.questions.each do |question|
    application.answers.build(question_id: question.id)
  end
end
```

And in the controller:

```
def new 
  @application = Application.new(job_id: params[:job_id])
  @application.build_answers
  redirect_to jobs_path, :notice => "You've already applied to this job! Check out some more" if has_job(current_user,@job)
end
```

That way, your view would look simpler:

```
<%= form_for @application do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :job_id, value: f.object.job_id %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.fields_for :answers do |a| %>
    <% question = a.object.question %>
    <%= a.label :content, question.content %>
    <%= a.text_area :content %>
    <%= a.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %> 
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit the application", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad that helped you! Btw, forgot something in the form_for. Added a hidden_field for application's job_id so that application creates with a job_id.